# Macro-assigned button does not work in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I created a button and I assigned a macro to it. The button does not work, but if I run the macro manually by using the "run" option in the developer tab or if I press the "play" button in the VBA window, everything works perfectly. I do not think that adding the code will be useful.

Regards,

Comment: Form button or Active-X button? If the latter, are you sure that you are not accidentally still in design mode? Also -- by "does not work" do you mean that nothing happens or do you mean that you get an error message?

Comment: In excel, in design mode, right click the button and choose "Assign Macro ..." to double check it is trying to run your macro, not "Button_Click". When trying to use the macro by clicking the button, make sure you are not in Design Mode.

Comment: @JohnColeman I used a form button (using "Shapes"). The button worked perfectly, but then I made some changes to the macro and now it doesn't work when called through the button (it does work perfectly when run manually).

Comment: As an experiment -- in the very first line of the macro put `msgbox "Macro called"`. Does the msgbox display when the button is clicked?

Comment: I fixed it by doing something very odd. I replaced some of the code within the macro. I assigned names to all the ranges used within the macro and replaced them in the code. Now it works.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible the macro got "un-assigned".

Right-click the button in design mode, and select "Assign Macro"

[image: "Assign Macro" dialog]

Re-assign the macro in the dialog, exit design mode and click the button - it should "just work".

Comment: I fixed it by doing something very odd. I replaced some of the code within the macro. I assigned names to all the ranges used within the macro and replaced them in the code. Now it works.

Comment: The button code works directly with F5, but when I assigned a procedure to the button and clicked it, nothing happened. When I looked, it showed no procedure assigned. 

Suddenly I've found that I was recording a macro. When I've stopped the record, normal operation has returned